# How to change the value of TextInput element in React Native?

Tags: react-native

How to call TextInput 'inputId' and change its value?

```
const AddItem = ({title, addItem}) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const onChange = (textValue) => setText(textValue)

    return(
    <View>
        <TextInput name = 'inputId' placeholder = 'Add Item...' style = {styles.input} onChangeText = {onChange}></TextInput>
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.btn} onPress = {() => {
            addItem(text);
            
        }
        }>
            <Text style = {styles.btnText}>Add Item</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wondering "How can I grab this node and change it like I would in the DOM using jQuery or simple Javascript", then the topic you're looking to research is react native refs. You can learn more here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Be warned though, using refs just to change values is likely NOT going to be how the framework prescribes you manage it. It's better to bind the component's "value" member (see jsur's response) in order to accomplish binding the value to the TextInput component (or other components) and just let react-native decide when to "update the JS object" internally.

Answer (score 3):

`TextInput` has a `value` prop that is the value that is shown for it: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#value.

Do remember to Google similar questions first, it'll often be faster than writing a question here!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got the question right but it seems that you are trying to accept input from the `TextInput` component and want to store them for rendering in the list.

**If that's the case then here is the full working example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/happy-bananas)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const handleAddItem = (value) => {
    setItems([...items, value]);
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <AddItem title={'Title'} addItem={handleAddItem} />
      <FlatList
        data={items}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={[styles.card, { backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.2)' }]}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const AddItem = ({ title, addItem }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const onChange = (textValue) => setText(textValue);

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        name="inputId"
        value={text}
        placeholder="Add Item..."
        style={[styles.card, { backgroundColor: 'rgba(21,21,21,0.1)' }]}
        onChangeText={onChange}></TextInput>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          addItem(text);
          setText('');
        }}>
        <View style={[styles.card, { backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)' }]}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>Add Item</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    margin: 5,
    padding: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
});
```